# Stored procedure doesn't do anything in remote server when called with "Exec procedure"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, exec

I'm puzzling with a Stored procedure that has different behavior when run with an withoout the Exec keyword.

I have 2 servers, **Server 1:**
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64)   Apr  2 2010 15:48:46   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.0  (Build 6002: Service Pack 2) (Hypervisor)

**Server 2:** 
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP2) - 10.0.4000.0 (X64)   Sep 16 2010 19:43:16   Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (VM)

A stored procedure (ACTUALIZA_MANTE_FULL) in Server 1 that deletes and inserts data to a table in Server 2 from tables in server 1. 
When I run "EXEC ACTUALIZA_MANTE_FULL" the process returns no errors but the destinatio table has no rows.
When I run "ACTUALIZA_MANTE_FULL" (without EXEC) the process runs with no errors and the data is inserted correctly.

Why the difference?, what i'm missing?

EDIT: procedure pseudo code (sorry can't put actual code)

`CREATE PROCEDURE MIPROC<br> 
AS <br>
  declare @from datetime<br>
  set @from = getdate()-30<br>
  <br>
  delete from [ADMSRV].remotedb.dbo.remoteTable where t_date >= @from<br>
  <br>
  Insert into [ADMSRV].remotedb.dbo.remoteTable <br>
  Select fields, sum(datum) as datum<br>
  form localdb.dbo.localtable1<br>
  where ld_date >= @from<br>
  group by ields <br>
  union <br>
  Select fields, sum(datum) as data<br>
  form localdb2.dbo.localtable2<br>
  where ld_date >= @from<br>
  group by fields<br>
GO<br>`

the fields  in (fields) are same cuantity, and type of PK in remoteTable
Remote table has PK only, no FK, no unique constraint, no unique index or triggers.

Comment: You should at least include the procedure code in your question and preferably try to do some debugging for example with profiler

Comment: Look for try/catch code that may silently be eating error messages. As @JamesZ said, run profiler, on both Server 2 and Server 1.